# Function not returning 0 due to comparison error

Tags: c, function

I'm new to programming.

The purpose of this function (validate) is to validate if the user has entered a correct command in the command prompt that being either: -h,-k,-f,-e, or -d. if the user hasn't done this then the program prints an error message returns a boolean zero to the main function and then ends the program. If the user uses one of the commands then instead it returns a 1 and the program continues in the main function.

However I'm getting this error message from the compiler:

> comparison between pointer and integer
>       ('bool (*)(char *, char *, int)' and 'int')
>   if (validate==1){"

This is my function:

```
bool validate(char* file_check, char* keyfile_check, int argc) {
  int validationcleared;
  if (strcmp(file_check, "-h") != 0 && strcmp(file_check, "-k") != 0 &&
    strcmp(file_check, "-f") != 0 && strcmp(file_check, "-e") != 0 &&
    strcmp(file_check, "-d") != 0) {
    printf("please use a valid file\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else if (strcmp(file_check, "-k") == 0 && (argc < 3)) {
    printf("please use a digit character for keyfile\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int validationcleared;
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: partb 1 2 3 \n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  char* filename = argv[1];
  char* keyfile = argv[2];

  validate(filename,keyfile, argc);
  if (validate==1) {
    printf("validation test passed\n");

  }

  else {
    printf("validation test not passed\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about indenting your code and adding the one or another empty line to improve readability?

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show but in the code that calls `validate`. [Edit] your question and show that code.

Comment: Don't put images instead of code.

Comment: Apparently you wrote `if (validate==1)` somewhere. `validate` is a function, not a number. You are supposed to *call* it.

Comment: I was going to retype for you, but your on your own here... Always post your actual code in text within your question indented by 4-spaces so it formats properly as code. (and unless you require to user to enter ALL options, then consider using `||` instead of `&&` in your conditional expression and consider `==` instead of `!=`) Your logic may be right, it's just not entirely clear what your goal is.

Comment: @Ben your last edit made it worse. Please post the  code where you call `validate`.

Comment: `validate(filename,keyfile, argc); if (validate==1){`  should be  `if (validate(filename,keyfile, argc)){`

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather common mistake among beginners:

```
validate(filename, keyfile, argc);
if (validate == 1) {
    // ....
```

If you want to check the return value from a function, you should use the actual function call, not the name of the function. Like this:

```
if (validate(filename, keyfile, argc) == 1) {
    // ....
```

Or, if you still want to do it in several steps:

```
bool result = validate(filename, keyfile, argc);
if (result == 1) {
    // ....
```